# Constructor called outside of main

Tags: c++, constructor, global-variables

I saw this question about constructors and I don't understand why the variable `a` is calling the constructor.

I thought it wass an error because the variable declaration is out of `main` without stating global before the name of it and they only wrote `a;` without the class name before it. How does the compiler know that the variable is of type `Test`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
      Test() { cout << "Hello from Test() "; }
} a;
 
int main()
{
    cout << "Main Started ";
    return 0;
}
```

The answer for the output was - *"Hello from Test() Main Started"*.

Comment: "without stating global before the name of it" ? you mean `global Test a;` ? Something like that does not exist in C++. Seems like you could use a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: The class name actually *is* there: `class Test a;` is an almost valid short hand pre-declaration of class and variable at the same time (almost because you cannot declare objects of incomplete type), equivalent to `class Test; Test a;`. Placing the class definition in between doesn't change anything about apart from that the type now is complete, making the whole stuff fully legal. It's not a recommended way to declare variables, though.

Comment: Side note: [about `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Answer (score 6):

As you might know, we have two ways to create an object from the `Test` class:

first, in the `main`:

```
class Test
        {
        public:
            Test() { cout << "Hello from Test() "; }
        };

int main()
{
    Test a;
    cout << "Main Started ";
    return 0;
}
```

Or before starting `main` in the definition of your class (like your code):

```
class Test
{
public:
      Test() { cout << "Hello from Test() "; }
} a;
 
int main()
{
    cout << "Main Started ";
    return 0;
}
```

In both cases, you are calling the constructor of the `Test` class once you make an object from it. In the `main` or before it.